# How can I include a linq expression to screen a list of generic items

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I am trying to use a linq expression to filter a list in a generic method and can't quite get it right.

Here is what it looks like:

the call:

```
         Expression<Func<SomeObject, object>> screen = i => i.BooleanFlag == false;
         SomeObjectList.Build<SomeObject>(
            screen,
            NonBuiltListOfTypeSomeObject);
        }
```

the method:

```
    public void Build<T>(
        Expression<Func<T,object>> screen,
        List<T> items) where T : class
    {
        this.Values = items.Select(f => new ModelForBuild()
        {
            //Build Parameters
        }).ToList();
    }
```

What I am trying to do is screen the items before they are built into `this.Values`. I pass in the linq expression trying to deny access based on the boolean property in `SomeObject`. However, the compiler tells me I cannot use

```
this.Values = items.Where(screen).Select(f => new ModelForBuild()...
```

I have tried various ways so maybe there is a better way to do this, if so, what is that way **OR** how can I effectively include the linq expression to screen the list of items?

**EDIT**

Error message from .Where(screen)

`Error  1   Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<T>'`

`Error  2   'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Where<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TSource,bool>>)' has some invalid arguments`

`Error  24  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<T,object>>' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<T,bool>>'`

Comment: You are returning an object instead of a boolean value. Change `Func<T, object>` to `Func<T, bool>` or `Predicate<T>`.

Comment: @AS-CII - Neither of those worked.

Comment: Are you using Linq to Objects or either of Linq to Sql/Entities?

Comment: @Phil - `using System.Linq.Expressions;` and `using System.Linq;` and `using System.Collections.Generic;`

Comment: If you are not using Linq To SQL you can't use Expressions this way. This is the definiton of `Where` function in `Enumerable` class (taken from MSDN): `Where<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, Boolean>)`

Comment: See edits for error message. The message was obtained if `Func<T,object>` was unchanged, changed to `Func<T,bool>`, or changed to `Predicate<T>`

Comment: @AS-CII - Is there a different method aside from Where I can use then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean something like this:

```
void Main()
{
    var builder = new Builder();
    var unbuilt = new List<ModelForBuild>();
    builder.Build<ModelForBuild>( m => m.Id == 0, unbuilt);
}

public class Builder
{
    public IEnumerable<ModelForBuild> Values{ get; private set; }

    public void Build<T>( Func<T, bool> screen, 
                          IEnumerable<T> items ) where T : class
    {
        Values = items.Where(screen).Select(
            i => new ModelForBuild{ Id = 1 }).ToList();
    }
}

public class ModelForBuild
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
}
```

You don't need to use `Expression<T>`.

Comment: @Phil - The compiler likes this setup, thank you for the tip on Expression.

Comment: @Phil - For a more complex question, would it be possible to include the screen inside of the `Build` method even though `Build` cannot know if `T` contains the screened property?

Comment: @Phil - Believe it or not I was able to accomplish the complex part through reflection, making the approach in this question less useful for me. However, I really appreciate you helping me with this issue of Expressions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish?
I think you misuse Expressions here.

Just use the Where method. It won't be executed until you iterate over the collection or use the ToList/ToArray/... Methods.

```
items.Where(i => i.BoolProperty).Select(i => new ModelForBuild()...
```

This will only instantiate mfb's for the items that passed the where predicate, and is the right way to do it, if I understand what you are ying to do.

Comment: @Yoyre Nathan - Cannot do that with generics because there is no definition for which fields they have.

Comment: @TravisJ I didn't understand the question. +1 for your answer.